# COMException when I use a Popup in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, popup

I have a very annoying exception which freeze my application thrown by WPF, when the content of this popup seems to have to much element.
In the output windows I see approximatively 50 times this exception.

> 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
>   occurred in UIAutomationProvider.dll

Then sometimes after the freeze I have this exception :

> ContextSwitchDeadlock was detected
>   Message: The CLR has been unable to
>   transition from COM context 0x3bd0048
>   to COM context 0x3bd01b8 for 60
>   seconds. The thread that owns the
>   destination context/apartment is most
>   likely either doing a non pumping wait
>   or processing a very long running
>   operation without pumping Windows
>   messages. This situation generally has
>   a negative performance impact and may
>   even lead to the application becoming
>   non responsive or memory usage
>   accumulating continually over time. To
>   avoid this problem, all single
>   threaded apartment (STA) threads
>   should use pumping wait primitives
>   (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and
>   routinely pump messages during long
>   running operations.

I don't use any COM component in my code, does someone already had this problem ?

The Deadlock is detected by the debugger and doesn't have any stacktrace.
The COM Exception stacktrace is :

> {"An event was unable to invoke any of
>   the subscribers (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80040201)"}
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
>
> at
>   MS.Internal.Automation.UiaCoreProviderApi.UiaHostProviderFromHwnd(IntPtr
>   hwnd)

When I call

```
popup.IsOpen = true
```

Comment: I had a similar issue, but I do not remember the context. Can you post the relevant code or a stacktrace?

Comment: Terrible bug to have in WPF 4.0, just sayin'.

Comment: While debugging a WPF app I had this exception occur when opening a Combobox's drop-down list. I had a mini-freak but couldn't recreate the issue. I also noticed that after the COM blowup my Win XP Mode virtual application windows disappeared (but were still running, apparently). Bizarre stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution is to make Visibility="Collapsed" on the content of the popup, instead of closing the popup, but it's a bit hacky.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. i guess it was related to a multitouch enabled dell monitor attached to my computer. when i a stopped the Tablet Input Service, the ComExceptions disappeared. maybe this is an option for you too.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by uninstalling a Wacom Pen and Touch tablet and disabling the Tablet Input Service.
I encountered this issue with WPF Popups (TogglePopups, Comboboxes, etc) and Expanders.